# A bit confused about a sesquilinear form property for $\mathbb{C}$ in Analysis Now.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $(\cdot, \cdot):V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ be a sesquilinear form.

Suppose $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$. Sorry if this is a dumb question since Pedersen said it's immediate, but why is $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is self-adjoint iff $(x, x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in V$?

The forward direction is obvious, but I have been having trouble with the reverse. Pedersen says to use this property $4(x| y) = \sum_{k = 0}^3 i^k(x + i^k y| x+ i^k y)$.

Comment: Use sequilinearity to write $(y\vert x)$ in terms of $(x\vert y)$ via the sum you mentioned.